# How to adjust the size of my wordpress header image to extend the full length of the page?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, image-size

I downloaded a theme which allows me to put in a header image, however I can't get the image to extend across the entire screen.

The site is www.tonicofwildness.com

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you header image/logo is not big enough and it's wrapped inside a "container" class.

You've to put the header image out of the container div.

Comment: @mmaurnio Thank you! I know what to do coding wise, but would I do this in the css or would I do this in one of the .php files? That is the part I'm a little confused about. I'm new to Wordpress and don't know too much about php yet. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Elizabeth The best way to do is from the html/php of the theme. It should be in the header.php file. If you want to do this from the css you can set the #header .container { overflow: visible; } . Then place anything in the header more than 1080 px. That'll overflow the container. It may require some css tweaks as well. Thank You